# How to register service without using parameters in constructor using Unit Test using .NET Core 6.0

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-6.0

I am working on an application where I want to run a simple get list test but it gives me the error shown in the image. Here is my code

I am registering service using a separate class here is the code

> ApplicationRegister

```
public static class ApplicationService
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Method to configure application level services with the di container
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="services"></param>
        /// <param name="configuration"></param>
        public static void ConfigureApplicationServices(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
              services.AddScoped<IWeatherServiceManager, WeatherServiceManager>();
              services.AddScoped<IHttpClientApiService, HttpClientApiService>();
        }
    }
```

> Program.cs

using weather_api.ServiceRegister;

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


// Add services to the container.

#region [Register Services]
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationServices();
#endregion
```

> WeatherServiceManager

```
public class WeatherServiceManager : IWeatherServiceManager
    {
        private readonly IHttpClientApiService httpClientApiService;
        private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

        public WeatherServiceManager(IHttpClientApiService httpClientApiService, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.httpClientApiService = httpClientApiService;
            this.configuration = configuration;
        }
       
    }
```

> Unit Test Class

```
   public class WeatherControllerTest
    {
        private readonly IWeatherServiceManager _weatherServiceManager;

        public WeatherControllerTest()
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            _weatherServiceManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<WeatherServiceManager>();

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get Weather details using zip code and city name
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [Fact]
        public async Task GetWeatherInformation()
        {
            // Act & Assert
            var items = Assert.IsType<List<WeatherViewModel>>(await _weatherServiceManager.GetForecast("London"));
            Assert.Equal(3, items.Count);
        }

    }
```

The Image below

[image]

here is the error I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you're testing your dependency injection registration:

```
public WeatherControllerTest()
{
    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    _weatherServiceManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<WeatherServiceManager>();
}
```

And you're doing that wrong.

First: test your DI code separately. You shouldn't be using your DI container in a unit test.

Second: you're not calling your extension method `ConfigureApplicationServices()` in your test.

Third: you're registering your manager with its interface: request it with that as well.

So create a test to test your DI code:

```
public class DependencyInjectionTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        // Arrange
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.ConfigureApplicationServices();
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        // Act
        var manager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IWeatherServiceManager>();
    }
}
```

And create a separate test fixture for the manager itself:

```
public class WeatherManagerTests
{
    private readonly IWeatherServiceManager _weatherServiceManager;

    public WeatherManagerTests()
    {
        var apiMock = new Mock<IHttpClientApiService>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        // ...
        _weatherServiceManager = new WeatherServiceManager(apiMock.Object, ...);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GetWeatherInformation()
    {
        // Act & Assert
        var items = Assert.IsType<List<WeatherViewModel>>(await _weatherServiceManager.GetForecast("London"));
        Assert.Equal(3, items.Count);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am facing an error when I run the test. Why ?

Comment: I have no idea, as I can't look at your screen.

Comment: I have shared a screen cast in my question

Comment: Yeah you should not do that. Copy and paste the error text and research it. I have addressed it in my answer though, try reading it. It's "Third: you're registering your manager with its interface: request it with that as well".

Comment: My WeatherServiceManager is also expecting another service as well. I have injected HttpClientService in WeatherServiceManager constructor

Comment: Yes, so you mock those dependencies. You had a question about a particular error, or are you looking for one on one tutoring for unit testing? For the latter I'll have to charge.

Comment: Okay Elon Musk. I got you